# How to find the code that generates graphs?

Tags: pandas, plotly-dash

Here is the code sample that you can find in the 'https://realpython.com/'

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("avocado.csv")
data = data.query("type == 'conventional' and region == 'Albany'")
data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
data.sort_values("Date", inplace=True)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
```

However, when I run this code, two graphs show up irrelevantly.
Where can I find the codes that generate these graphs? Why do these graphs occur?

[image: figure_0]

[image: figure_1]

Comment: In `app.layout`. Scroll down in the same article you're referring to https://realpython.com/python-dash/. The code in your question is not all the code you're trying since a dash app requires its layout property to be set. So nothing is generated irrelevantly.

Comment: I tried that too but it didn't solve my problem. I think the problem is caused by the dash. Because whenever I add the "import dash", I see these graphs when I run the code. I dont understand why this is so.

Comment: Share the code you're running, otherwise there is no way to say what's going on exactly. Do these figures show up in separate browser by the way, or are they on the same page as the dash app? If it's the former check if you do `fig.show()` or something similar anywhere.

Comment: I am not running any other code other than the code I shared above. Whenever I remove the "import dash" only then the graphs do not appear.